# check if any of the items of a list is in a line of a file, if not, then write the line in a new file

Tags: python

I have a file that has a lot of lines and I need to create a new file, excluding the lines that contains some words.

Have created a code which is working, but there are a lot of words, so, that would be better store these words in a list and verify the items of that list. Following the code:

```
infile = file('./infile_test.txt')
newopen = open('./newfile.txt', 'w')

for line in infile:
    if 'ssh' not in line and 'snmp' not in line and 'etc' not in line:
        newopen.write(line)
```

That is an example, but supposing that infile_test.txt had the lines below, a new file would be created, excluding lines 2,4 and 6 :

```
line 1: this is a file test
line 2: ssh, snmp
line 3: the idea is to iterate in each line of this file
line 4: if the list of words (ssh,etc) does not appears in any of the line
line 5: then write the line in another file
line 6: etc
line 7: itens have been removed or not ?
```

I believe that creating a list like:

```
list = ['ssh', 'snmp', 'etc']
```

and then iterating over that comparing each of the list itens could be better, have tried doing a new "for", used "all" and "any" function, but didn´t work well.

Anyone knows a better way for achieving that ?

Comment: How did you try those. I believe using nested-for (the one u r saying) is good enough

Comment: `for x in mylist: if x in line : continue `

Comment: using 'list' as the variable name for a python list you shouldn't do.  There are special words list,dict,etc that should not be variable names even though it seems python allows this.  Got burned by that one myself.

Comment: @Darshan, thank you, have tested with your suggestions, but that writes the lines that contains the words, have tested as if x not in line, but it writes the words multiple times. Thank you anyway for commenting on that

Comment: @don_q, thank you, didn't know about that variable name, will modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
infile = file('./infile_test.txt')
outfile = open('./newfile.txt', 'w')

ignore_list = ['ssh', 'snmp', 'etc']

for line in infile:
    if not any(word in line for word in ignore_list):
        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
infile = open('./infile_test.txt')
newopen = open('./newfile.txt', 'w')
words = ['ssh', 'snmp', 'etc']
for line in infile:
    found = True
    for word in words:
        if word in line:
            found = False
    if not found:
        newopen.write(line)
```

Comment: You are doing it opposite i guess

Comment: Yep :). Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
infile = file('./infile_test.txt')
newopen = open('./newfile.txt', 'w')
ignoreList = ['ssh', 'snmp', 'etc']
for line in infile:
    showLine = True
    for i in ignoreList:
        if i in line:
            showLine = False

    if showLine:
        newopen.write(line)

 # Don't forget to close the files
 infile.close()
 newopen.close()
```

Comment: have tested that, but didn't work. Thank you anyway for taking the time.

Comment: fixed it . thanks for the comment.  The accepted answer is the most up to date and 'pythonic' anyhow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
word_list = ['ssh', 'snmp', 'etc']
result_lines = []
for line in infile:
    if all(line.lower().find(word.lower()) < 0 for word in word_list):
        result_lines.append(line)
newopen.writelines(result_lines)
```

Comment: omu_negru and Darshan, that worked great as well ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

**Full script:**

```
my_unwanted_words = set(['ssh', 'snmp', 'etc'])
with open("infile_test.txt", 'r') as infile, open("newfile.txt", 'w') as newopen:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    [newopen.write(line) for line in lines if not (set(line.split()) & my_unwanted_words)]
```

**First line:**

```
my_unwanted_words = set(['ssh', 'snmp', 'etc'])
```

Use a set for your collection of unwanted words.  Sets only permit unique values, so if you were to read these in from a file or in some other way amass a large collection of them, you'd have no duplicates.  Also, you get to use the intersection set operator '&' later in the script.

**Second line:**

```
with open("infile_test.txt", 'r') as infile, open("newfile.txt", 'w') as newopen:
```

It is considered good practice to open files using 'with' because it does extra housekeeping such as automatically closing the file when you're finished with it.  Note that you can open both files in this one line.

**Third line:**

```
    lines = infile.readlines()
```

lines is now a list of strings, each string represents one of the lines from the original file.

**Fourth and last line:**

```
    [newopen.write(line) for line in lines if not (set(line.split()) & my_unwanted_words)]
```

Here is where the real work is done.  This is a list comprehension that only returns a line to be written `newopen.write(line)` if there is no intersection `&` between the set of words in the current line `set(line.split())` and your set of unwanted words `my_unwanted_words`.

I went a little lazy with the script above, leaving a final solution up to you.  Without further specification split() will only separate your line into words based on white space.  So if you have one of your unwanted words hiding within parens or adjacent to other punctuation, as you do with line 4 of the input file, split() will return a single troublesome word...

```
(ssh,etc)
```

...which does not match anything in your unwanted list and therefore passes through to newfile.txt.  Play with arguments to split() to fix that.  You might also check out Python's re module to replace line.split() with a regular expression of some sort.

Good luck!